# Vue.js named router-link not generated

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I try to use `<router-link>` to generate a link to a view but it does not generate the proper link.

In a TS componenent :

```js
      <div id="nav">
        <ul class="menu-list">
          [...]
          <li><router-link to="{name: 'profile'}">Profile section 2</router-link></li>
          <li><router-link to="/about">About section</router-link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

In `router/index.ts` :

```js
import Profile from '../views/Profile.vue'

[...]
{
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'profile',
    component: Profile,
    props: true
  },
[...]
```

Here is the link "generated" :
`<a data-v-25a8ea9c="" href="/ui/{name: 'profile'}" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">Profile section 2</a>`
And of course, the page show me my custom 404 error.

The `About` link is well generated :
`<a data-v-25a8ea9c="" href="/ui/about" class="">About section</a>`

Comment: You are supposed to use `:to="{name: 'profile'}"` but you aren't prepending the colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:to` but you are using `to` without the colons:

Replace:

```js
<li><router-link to="{name: 'profile'}">Profile section 2</router-link></li>
```

With:

```js
<li><router-link :to="{name: 'profile'}">Profile section 2</router-link></li>
```

Notice the `:` that I've prepended there before `to`. In the absence of the leading `:`, you aren't binding the Vue instance to this element thus Vue router doesn't recognize this as a valid path.